# When a string is used as an input into numpy.mat(), certain characters are ignored

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy

Coming to scipy/numpy from MATLAB, I regard the input syntax to numpy.array as overly parenthesis-heavy, e.g.

```
import numpy as np
import math
np.array([[1, 2], [math.sqrt(3), 4]])
```

The following MATLAB-like syntax therefore appeals to me:

```
np.array(np.mat("1, 2; math.sqrt(3), 4"))
```

However, this particular example apparently results in the array

```
array([[ 1. ,  2. ],
       [ 0.3,  4. ]])
```

It seems that numpy.mat() ignores some characters in its input string: in this case "math" and "sqrt". Furthermore, it seems that it is not possible to use variables in the input string. Why is that? And is there a way to use a MATLAB-like, paranthesis-thrifty input method that isn't "broken" in this way?

Comment: Huh, that does [seem to be the case](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.8.0/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py#L41). It is possible to do this by modifying `numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix._eval`, but giving access to the variables in the current scope may be a little tricky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `eval()` and `sys._getframe()` to write a function, here is an example:

```
import numpy as np

def m(s):
    import sys
    frame = sys._getframe(1)
    return np.array([eval(item.strip(), frame.f_globals, frame.f_locals) 
                         for item in s.split(";")])

def f():
    a = 1
    x = 3.14
    print m("1,2,3;np.sin(a),np.sqrt(2),x")

f()
```

Comment: If you get the 4th stack frame instead of the 1st, you can just replace `np.matrixlib.defmatrix._eval` with `eval` (after adding in the globals and locals) and make OP's original code work as-is: http://bpaste.net/show/6XVUCeqE5MadYo9fwzr2/

Comment: Your answer exactly addresses my question, thanks! My conclusion, however, is that I'd better stick to the standard syntax to avoid complications :).